# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout - how to create multiple horizontal sections?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I want to achieve this layout (I'm talking about that horizontal section):

[image: layout]

I know, that I can't have multiple sections horizontally side by side, when my layout is vertical by default. But can I achieve something similar just with groups and items within one section? Only solution that I can think off is some usage of combinated absolute sized nested groups and items. But it's based strictly on number of items in this section and it just does not feels right in the context of compositional layout.

Am I overlooking something? Or it is just impossible?

I know, that I can use nested collection view in one cell, but I'm curious about solution within one layout.

Comment: Searching comes up with a lot of info. These two articles (I have no association with them) may be good places to start: https://lickability.com/blog/getting-started-with-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/ and https://www.zealousweb.com/how-to-use-compositional-layout-in-collection-view/ ... both look like they have discussions / examples close to what you're asking.

Comment: None of those articles answers my question. They have basic horizontal section with one repeating group. And trust me, I have done a lot of searching already :)